# Option labels do not show up

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

As you can see in the code, i send "ttypes" to select-option menu. "ttypes" includes a list which has two elements and i want to show these elements as option but when i do that operation, jtsl creates two options but these options  don't have any values. I cannot see anything.

I post a list as an attibute below.

```
model.addAttribute("ttypes", technicalTypeService.getTechnicalType());
```

And then i want to show that list in the select-option menu
but i cannot see the values in the select-option menu.
Can anyone help me?

```
<c:forEach items="${ttypes}" varStatus="i">
<c:set var="name" value="${ttypes[i.index].name}" />
<option value="${name}"</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Disclaimer: I'll for simplicitly assume that the invalid HTML syntax (a missing `>`) is just caused by carelessness during preparing the question.*</sup>

---

You've definitely set the option values. Rightclick the page in your favourite webbrowser and choose *View Source*. Look closer, they are there in the generated HTML output.

You only forgot to set the option **labels**. Labels are visible to the enduser while values are indeed invisible to the enduser. You can set the option label by setting the body of the `<option>` element.

```
<c:forEach items="${ttypes}" varStatus="i">
    <c:set var="name" value="${ttypes[i.index].name}" />
    <option value="${name}">${name}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

A less clumsy way is:

```
<c:forEach items="${ttypes}" var="ttype">
    <option value="${ttype.name}">${ttype.name}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Noted should be that usually some technical ID is been used as option value.

```
<c:forEach items="${ttypes}" var="ttype">
    <option value="${ttype.id}">${ttype.name}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Also noted should be that when you omit the value, then the label becomes implicitly the option value.

```
<c:forEach items="${ttypes}" var="ttype">
    <option>${ttype.name}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Finally, noted should be that this problem has got nothing to do with JSP/JSTL/Spring. They are in the context of this question merely acting as a HTML code generator. Your concrete problem is just related to basic HTML.

#### See also:

- [HTML beginner tutorial](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/) - [forms](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/html/beginner/forms/) - select

Answer (score 0):

try with something like that:

```
<c:forEach items="${ttypes}" var="ttype" varStatus="i">
   <option value="${ttype.name}">my label ?</option>
</c:forEach>
```

replace the "my label?" with whatever field in ttype contains the label.